# why the index is different when segmentfault occurs

Tags: c

At first, I wrote the code below (I know the code is bad, but just for testing):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    printf("%d", ints[-44]); //ints[-552] will not encounter segmentfault in my machine
}
```

the memory address of **ints** in my machine is 0x600840, and in my machine the size of a memory page is 4096 bytes, thus, the memory address between 0x600000 and 0x600fff is readable, so I it will not encounter `segmentfault` until ints[-553] (552 * 4 == 0x840).

However, when I change the code to below one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    ints[-44] = 0; 
}
```

at this time, segmentfault will occurs when using the statement `ints[-512] = 0`, but in the first version of code, `printf("%d", ints[-512])` will not encounter segmentfault.

My question is what causes this? and how could I determine the threshold that will cause segmentfault when using `ints[threshold + 1] = 0` while `ints[threshold]` will not cause segmentfault?

Comment: @JeffRSon YOu can't rely on it is right. But a race condition is about timing. Something completey different than this one.

Comment: @JeffRSon, glglgl is pointing out that timing is not the issue here. Talking about race conditions here is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: There's an article [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/07/why-does-my-code-not-crash/) about why some out-of-bounds accesses don't segfault

Comment: You cannot expect any consistency in manifestations of undefined behavior. Having two different programs with UB doesn't help here either. You *could* infer something (not very reliably) if all your tests were made with the same executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading is another operation than writing. The page before the writable data segment might be read-only. Let's have a look.

I modified your first program this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    printf("%d", ints[-44]); //ints[-552] will not encounter segmentfault in my machine
    close((int)&ints);
    sleep(100);
}
```

so that in the `strace` output the address will become evident. I ran it and got `134520896` which is `0x804a040`. Having a look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` reveals

```
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 5275899    /tmp/a
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 00:21 5275899    /tmp/a
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 00:21 5275899    /tmp/a
...
```

i. e. the address is 64 bytes behind the start of that page. The memory before that is read-only.

If I do the same with the 2nd program:

```
int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    close((int)&ints);
    ints[-44] = 0;
    sleep(100);
}
```

I get `134520896` = `0x804a040` as well.

The map is the same as above:

```
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 5277100    /tmp/b
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 00:21 5277100    /tmp/b
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 00:21 5277100    /tmp/b
...
```

An offset of `-44`, counted in ints, reduces the address by `44 * sizeof(int)`, i. e. `176` = `0xb0`, which leads me to `0x804a040-0xb0 = 0x8049f80`, which lies in the read-only area `08049000-0804a000`. Reading this does not cause any sefgault, but writing does.

Under the given circumstances, I shouldn't get a segfault until `ints[-2064]`, as this has an address of `0x8048000`. But as you might have a different compiler, library, settings etc. than me, you might encounter other limits. And as you know, with undefined behaviour, you'll never be safe.

But let's test that as well:

In order to avoid using `printf()`, which might change segment sizes, I do

```
int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i--;
        close(i);
        close((int)&ints[i]);
        ints[i] = ints[i];
    }
}
```

and have a look at the strace output, which reads

```
close(-15)                              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(134520836)                        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(-16)                              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(134520832)                        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(-17)                              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(134520828)                        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x8049ffc} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

where `134520832 = 0x804a000` and `134520828 = 0x8049ffc`. I may not write -> SIGSEGV.

If I just read:

```
int ints[20] = {10, 20};
int main()
{
    int i = 0; int j;
    while (1) {
        i--;
        close(i);
        close((int)&ints[i]);
        j = ints[i];
    }
}
```

I indeed get until

```
close(-2064)                            = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(134512640)                        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(-2065)                            = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(134512636)                        = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x8047ffc} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

where `134512640 = 0x8048000` and `134512636 = 0x8047ffc`. This is outside my mapped memory and I even am disallowed to read.

Answer (score 2):

Reading and writing outside the bounds of memory you have allocated is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Invoking this undefined behaviour usually (but not always) results in a segfault. **However, you can't be *sure* that a segfault will happen.**

The wikipedia link explains it quite nicely:

> When an instance of undefined behavior occurs, so far as the language specification is concerned anything could happen, maybe nothing at all.

So, in this case, you could get a segfault, the program could abort, or sometimes it could just run fine. Or, anything. There is no way of guaranteeing the result.

You asked:

> how could I determine the threshold that will cause segmentfault?

Since `ints` is an array of 20 items, the only indexes where you can be sure a segfault wont happen are 0-19. You can't write code that you are certain will trigger a segmentation fault across systems. This [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html) explains it quite well:

> — Macro: int SIGSEGV
>
> This signal is generated when a program tries to read or write outside the memory that is allocated for it, or to write memory that can only be read. (**Actually, the signals only occur when the program goes far enough outside to be detected by the system's memory protection mechanism.**) The name is an abbreviation for “segmentation violation”.
>
> Common ways of getting a SIGSEGV condition include dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer, or when you use a pointer to step through an array, but fail to check for the end of the array. It varies among systems whether dereferencing a null pointer generates SIGSEGV or SIGBUS.

(emphasis added)

Comment: but when considering using `printf("%d", ints[index])` case, I could compute that when index is between -552 and 0, it will not segfault. while when using 'ints[index] = 0', I could not compute it out.

Comment: Ah, but you can't be **sure** that it won't segfault within those values. Since behaviour varies between systems/compilers etc. Accessing indexes outside of 0-19 causes "undefined behaviour": you can't know what will happen.

Comment: @Charles0429 By knowing that programs acquire memory from the system in 4096 byte pages in your operating system you knew that part of memory was assigned to your process. Apparantly, `ints[-44]` has been marked read-only. Knowing why it has been marked read-only probably requires intimate knowledge on how your compiler/linker sets up memory when the program is executed.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck If you can gather the addresses and can have a look on the memory maps, you can derive why the system behaves as it does.